# Reading a file without reading the whole thing into memory

Tags: c++, xml

I am trying to read an extremely large text file. I want to write a program (C++) to read it line by line until I reach a certain set of characters, then begin to write the following text into a string until it reaches another set of characters.

It is a XML file, so I'm looking at

```
<flag>info</flag>
```

I need my program to read the file until it reaches `<flag>`, inputs "info" into a a string and notes that `</flag>` is the point to stop putting stuff into the string. What tools could I utilize that can actually read the file. As far as detecting the `<flag>`, I can do that.

Comment: Have you tried just using `grep -oe "<flag>.*?</flag>"?

Comment: Are you suggesting we write your code for you?  Do you have code, or even pseudo-code, or an outline, to share with us?  Please articulate a problem, and pose a question that we may answer.

Comment: @ked, did you see my answer? What's wrong with SAX?

Comment: what's with all the hate?  This seemed like a reasonable, succinct question.  And @bdonlan's answer below would help do what he wants - process a file as a stream without reading the entire contents into memory.

Comment: @Tim: It read like a request to "write this code for me". I'm not sure the OP meant it that way. I, and others, edited it into its current form, with less of a rent-a-coder feel, and voted to reopen. You can do the same, if you agree.

Comment: @Tim:  The question as originally asked didn't even pose a question.  It just described a problem.   Later edits got slightly better, asking how to achieve the goal.  However, most people of S.O. insist that posters demonstrate some level of effort.   Asking extremely vague questions without a demonstrated attempt at a solution and a description of a roadblock is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @abelenky: ok, I see what you mean.  I gave him the benefit of the doubt, and I read it as a frustrated coder going "what the heck, DOM reads the entire file before I can do anything, and then my program runs out of memory!  how can I do this?"  Obviously he didn't mention DOM (or anything else), but having been there, my brain filled in such gaps.  Regardless, bdonlan's answer is a good one, and I can easily envision people getting to this page through a google search.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed.  The question was clear and relevant.  It was elementary, but since when has that been a reason to close?

Comment: I still think it's pretty low-quality, but I reckon it's ok for re-opening now.

Comment: Of for Christ's sake, all I wanted is for someone to help me out on how to open a damn text file without swamping my memory. I guess I never made it clear enough I do not know ANYTHING about accessing documents in C++.

Comment: ked, bdonlan gave the correct answer, below. Follow that lead.

Comment: I saw his answer and I am trying it right now and I am grateful. Unlike everyone else, he told me something else then to go screw myself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an XML SAX parser such as [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/); they will allow you to parse the XML file in a streaming fashion, so you don't need to load it into memory all at once. Reading line-by-line will not give you correct results on general XML files.